# How do I send POST Json and Image to php alamofire

Tags: php, json, swift, post, alamofire

I am able to send post data as json fine from swift using this code:

```
private func alamoFireAjax(url: String, parameters: Parameters, callback: @escaping (DataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON(completionHandler: callback)
}
```

But I want to send a image along with the data that this function is sending. How do I do that in alamofire, or do I need a different framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need convert(encode) image to base64 and send to PHP as a string, after receiving post PHP can decode it and save in the storage or save base64 string.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, will accept answer.